Is a linear regression model able to figure out the relation of division among two features?
I have a dataset that consists of data about students. The features are things such as passed credits, failed credits, semester among with other features. The target is the student's gpa. I believe that while the passed credits and failed credits don't have a direct correlation to the gpa (since they depend on the amount of the time students spent on the school), the values of passed credits / semester and failed credits / semester highly affect the outcome of the model. I want to know what is the best method of passing the data to a linear regression model? Should I pass passed credits / semester and failed credits / semester to the model and ignore passed credits and failed credits or vice versa? Or should I leave the data untouched and the model will figure out the relation itself?

What you mentioned is called feature engineering, i.e., the process of using domain knowledge to create new features or modify existing ones in a way that makes machine learning algorithms work more effectively.
Given a training set $X=\left\{x^{(i)}, y^{(i)} \right\}_{i=1}^{m}$, with $x^{(i)} \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ being the $i$-th sample, and $y^{(i)} \in \mathbb{R}$ the outcome, if you think the ratio of two features $X_1/X_2$ is more relevant to the prediction of $y$ than $X_1$ and $X_2$ separately, then you should compute this new hand-crafted feature, and drop $X_1$ and $X_2$ (see avoiding collinearity below).
However, training a linear regression on $X_1$ and $X_2$ versus training on the new feature $\frac{X_1}{X_2}$ results in fundamentally different models.  The linear regression model is defined by:
$$
\hat{y}^{(i)} = \vartheta_0 + \vartheta_1 x^{(i)}_1 + \vartheta_2 x^{(i)}_2 + \ldots + \vartheta_n x^{(i)}_n
$$
where $\hat{y}^{(i)}$ is the predicted value for the $i$-th sample. By contrast, if we introduce the new feature $\frac{x^{(i)}_1}{x^{(i)}_2}$, the model becomes:
$$
\hat{y}^{(i)} = \vartheta_0 + \vartheta_1 \frac{x^{(i)}_1}{x^{(i)}_2} + \vartheta_3 x^{(i)}_3 + \ldots + \vartheta_n x^{(i)}_n
$$
Here, the ratio $\frac{X_1}{X_2}$ is weighted by a single parameter, $\vartheta_1$, instad of $\vartheta_1$ and $\vartheta_2$ separetely. This modification changes the model’s architecture (i.e., the number of trainable parameters $\vartheta_k$) and therefore the model's performance.
Avoid collinearity
A good rule is that of dropping from your training set linearly dependent features. Suppose you have two different features, $X_1$ and $X_2$, that are linearly dependent  (or collinear):
$$X_2 = aX_1 + b$$
where $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$. Generally, linear regression is implemented based on normal equations, i.e., a method which gives you the best linear model that fits your data, rather than optimizing the model's weights by means of gradient-based optimization algorithms. Given a training set $X \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ and a target $y \in \mathbb{R}^{m}$, the weights $\vartheta \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ of the linear regression model are computed as follows:
$$ \vartheta = \left(X^T X \right)^{-1} X^T y$$
As you can see, an inverse matrix appears in the formula. In order to compute $A^{-1}$, the constant $\frac{1}{|A|}$ must be computed, with $|A|$ being the determinant of $A$. However, if $A$ has linear dependent rows/cols, $|A|=0$, thus $\frac{1}{|A|}$ is not defined. This also implies that $A^{-1}$ cannot be computed, and you cannot train a linear regression model under these assumptions.

Thanks for the accurate and thorough response!
